# How to disable text decoration with CSS?

Tags: css, text-styling

So, I need to remove a visited link coloring from my navigation bar, as it will look ugly.

I have tried to use `text-decoration: none;` and `color: white;` but that does not seem to help it.

[image: Still looks like this]

[CSS for navigation](https://pastebin.com/ZZS6UNeX)

[Actual code](https://pastebin.com/yw8fEssB)

*I removed the actual links from the code, in the real version there is link but for this question links are replaced with #*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to [Bariock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53877719/2358222), this will help reset your `<a>` links in all circumstances to your specified css.

```
a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
   color: yourColor !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   outline: none !important;
}
```

The `!important` signifies that it has a higher precedence than that of other rules declaring the same values for the same selectors. Note: you can still style them separately such like you would with `:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a:visited{
    color: your-color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited the `<a>` tag to go around the `<button>` so the text is back to white now and the button actually works. It is no longer just "click text to visit link" the whole button works.

```
<a href="#"><button class="dropbtn">Community</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a !important to the end of the css styles like so:

```
a {
   color: white !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you first set the style of the link tag, for example:

```
.dropdown a{ color:#fff }
```

now your text links inside the container with the class .dropdown will be as white color. Then you don't need to set a visited link color, unless you want to set it.

If you want to get rid the underline in the link, your style will be like this:

```
.dropdown a{ color:#fff; text-decoration: none; }
```